# Error connecting a Mongodb Cluster [MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02-jm5fl.mongodb.net:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I uploaded my Node JS application to my CPanel server, and I receive this error when raising the server.
I tried whitelist on the Mongo Atlas page but it didn't work either.

```
mongodb+srv://{myuser}:{mypassword}@cluster0-jm5fl.mongodb.net/fitcamglow?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

````
(node:2753308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02-jm5fl.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 34.236.173.137:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/lablanquita/storefitcamglow/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at connect (/home/lablanquita/storefitcamglow/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at makeConnection (/home/lablanquita/storefitcamglow/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/home/lablanquita/storefitcamglow/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at Socket.err (/home/lablanquita/storefitcamglow/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:281:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
(node:2753308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2753308) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: You "tried" the whitelist how exactly?

Comment: In Network Access I configured an entry as `0.0.0.0/0 (includes your current IP address)` and it is active

Comment: The connection works for me.

Comment: When I try it locally there is no problem, the problem is when I try to make the connection from the CPanel

Comment: Make a trouble ticket with the hosting company?